# Is there any way to change Bootstrap CSS icon on mouse hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-icons

I have a Bootstrap dropdown in Angular. For dropdown menu I am using bootstrap css [chevron-right](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/chevron-right/) icon. When user mouse hover, I want to change it to [chevron-down](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/chevron-down/) icon.

This is my code

```
<style>
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu{
        display: block;
    }
    .dropdown-menu{
        margin-top: 0;
    }
</style>

<div class="col-md-3 changeIcon">
    <div class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">A-E
            <i style="float: right;" class="bi bi-chevron-right"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Inbox</a>
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Sent</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

These css classes I tried but its not working

```
  .changeIcon{
    content: '\F285';
   }

   .changeIcon2:hover i::before{
    content: "\uF356";
  }
```

This is my UI, when user mouse hover, dropdown menus showing up but along with that I am not able to change right side icon

[image]

How can I do that ?

Comment: You can try to add `!important` to your css property.

Comment: I suppose you are clashing with `class="bi bi-chevron-right"` (probably bootstrap uses !important). Using `!important` yourself might work as suggested by @Flo or you could remove `bi-chevron-right` from the template and set both variants yourself (directly on the icon).

Comment: @GunnarB. - Even setting icon from css is not working. I tried this   `.changeIcon{
    content: "\F285" !important;
   }` and `<i class="changeIcon"></i>` inside anchor tag.

Comment: @Flo - Its not helping seems.  I tried.

Comment: you can only set the `content` of pseudo elements (::after and ::before)

Comment: It may perhaps help if you edit your question as a snippet and provide a working example

Comment: I had my answer made with fontawesome and since I think the point was made already I just removed it

Answer (score 0):

I have different solution for you.Here what i have try for you.

```
 <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        A-E
        <i class="bi bi-chevron-right icon"></i>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Apply following css to it

```
.btn.show .icon::before {
   transform: rotate(90deg);
   transition: transform 0.5s;
}
```

And if you want to rotate icon on dropdown hover then replace above css with this one.

```
.dropdown:hover .icon::before {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}
```

Hope you like it :)